# In C#, must an int be positive, negative or zero exclusively?

Tags: c#, int, language-lawyer

**TL; DR;**

Does the C# language ensure that an `int` must have **one and only one** of the following properties?

1. strictly greater than `0`
2. strictly less than `0`
3. equals to `0`

---

To be precise with an example, is this assertion guaranteed to never fail ?

```
public void CheckFacts(int n) 
{
    int trueFacts = 0;

    if (n > 0) trueFacts += 1;
    if (n == 0) trueFacts += 1;
    if (n < 0) trueFacts += 1;

    Assert.AreEqual(trueFacts, 1); 
}
```

---

Follow-up question : If yes, is that true as well for the various integer types ? (uint, long, ulong, sbyte, byte, short, ushort, ...)

---

For those who might think that this question is a bit off, don't forget that computer numbers can be surprising.

For instance, this is not the case that a `double` must be positive, negative or zero exclusively. It can be `NaN`<strike>, it can be `+0.0` or `-0.0`, 3</strike> values that will cause the above assertion to fail.

---

**EDIT:**

Someone made the remark that I somehow spent time writing this question but not one minute looking at the specs. I actually spent quite a lot of time reading : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx , because `int` is supposed to be an alias for `System.Int32`. I am honestly not sure that there was a clear cut on my question. Also, I thoroughly searched [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) questions on SO, because I thought that someone must have been asking this before. Sorry if such question seems obvious for some people, it was not to me.

Comment: There is a huge difference in calculating with floating point precision numbers and integral numbers.

Comment: Even for `double` it's not as bad as you seem to think. For `NaN` the assertion will fail, but not for +0.0 or -0.0.

Comment: So you read the documentation, and didn't see the section that specifically listed what the possible values are?  It's literally the first thing that the documentation covers in the remarks section.  Did you also not look at the section at the end of the remarks that explains what the underlying representation of the value is, which would *also* answer your question?

Comment: @servy I read the documentation on double, and it specifies a range of values as well. ±5.0 × 10−324 to ±1.7 × 10308 .

Comment: @Servy: How many more passes do we have to make on the comments here?

Comment: @BoltClock Depends on how many more times you're going to delete constructive comments pointing out how a post can be improved.

Comment: Nothing that's been deleted has pointed out how the post can be improved. It's merely pointed out why you think he hasn't done enough research on his own to justify the question. A single comment to that end *might* have been okay (but not really necessary; remember we aren't supposed to explain our downvotes), but >25 of them is not okay. Accept that people disagree with you and move on. Surely there are other things that demand your attention.

Comment: @Pac0 The documentation on double also goes on to explain what the non-numeric values are for that type, so it's not like the double documentation omits all reference to non-numeric values that exist.  And again, the `int` documentation also covers the underlying representation of the number, which shows that the values are all meaningful.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not explaining downvotes, I'm explaining how the author of the question could have (and still can) improve their question so that it's an appropriate question for the site by doing the appropriate research, indicating what they've done, and how it fails to properly answer their question, and I responded to a few replies with further clarification.  I have never mentioned downvotes, nor am I explaining them.

Comment: I was mostly asking for clarification, and i agree that I didn't pointed out in my question that I had indeed read documentation, without understanding the key points on which I was asking clarification. But those clarifications you put in some of your comments would have made a suitable answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

An `int` in C# is a 2's complement integral type with no unused bits. Every bit pattern is associated with a unique integral value. There is no room for things like infinities, "not a numbers", &c. (That uniqueness also applies to `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, &c.)

For the avoidance of doubt, there is no *signed zero*, which is a property of signed magnitude and 1's complement schemes.

Note also, for an IEEE754 floating point `double`, your code *would* work with a signed negative zero, since `0.0` is defined to be equal to `-0.0`, and `0.0 > -0.0` is `false`. You are correct that it would fail on `NaN`.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int